# Eventmachine linux system process kill

Tags: eventmachine

I'm using Eventmachine to run a linux/ubuntu system command to run a script. On occasion the running script hangs/freezes. My question is, how can I in the event loop, kill the script pid.

I have tried the following

```
EM.system(cmd) do |output,status|
  EM.add_timer(5) do
   Process.kill("Term",status.pid)
  end
end
```

The process id, i get from status.pid is not the process id of the script. I'm not sure which process id EM.system returns.

Answer (score 0):

The Eventmachine#system method takes a call proc callback.

```
def terminate_after_timeout
  proc do |process|
    EM.add_timer(60) do
      Process.kill('TERM', process.get_pid)
    end
  end
end

EM.run {
  EM.system(cmd,terminate_after_timeout) do |out,status|
    puts out
  end
end
```

This is one of the few clean strategies i found works quite well. The system cmd process will be killed after a given time, in this case 60 seconds